# How to write a Criteria Query where the table schema is an input parameter and it avoids SQL injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, db2, criteria-api

I have been attempting to find a way to write the following query to avoid any sort of SQL injection but have continually come up empty handed.

```
"SELECT NEXTVAL FOR " + schema + ".CNTCT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1"
```

I have tried using the `EntityManager` and `setParameter()` as such:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT NEXTVAL FOR ?.CNTCT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1");
query.setParameter(1, schema);
```

But that doesn't work because the positional parameter can only be used in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause of a SQL statement. Similar results when using a named parameter.

Those failures led me to try out Criteria Queries since they use a prepared statements. I was only really able to find examples of Criteria Queries that are extremely simple ie. `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = "JOHN"`. I could not find anything that was similar to what I needed.

Since I couldn't find what I needed and due to my time constraint I ventured into the forbidden OpenAI territory. The Criteria Query I received there still doesn't work... surprise surprise. But it is certainly different from all of the other CQ examples I found.

```java
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Integer> query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);

        ParameterExpression<String> schemaNameParam = cb.parameter(String.class);
        Expression<String> sequenceExpression = cb.concat(cb.concat(cb.literal("NEXTVAL FOR "), schemaNameParam), cb.literal(".CNTCT_ID"));
        Expression<String> sequenceString = cb.function("COALESCE", String.class, sequenceExpression, cb.literal("0"));
        query.select(cb.function("CAST", Integer.class, sequenceString));
        query.from(DummySequenceEntity.class);

        TypedQuery<Integer> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
        typedQuery.setParameter(schemaNameParam, schema);

        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

With that Criteria Query I am running into issues with the `CAST` it seems. Any assistance would be appreciated. I just want a SQL injection safe sequence query where the schema is variable depending on the `systemProperties` but that seems to be much more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may use HBN ~internal API to get next value of arbitrary sequence, something like:

```java
public class SequenceManager {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public long getNextValue(String sequenceName) {
        Dialect dialect = getDialect();
        String sql = dialect.getSequenceNextValString(sequenceName);
        return Optional.of(entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql))
                .map(Query::getSingleResult)
                .flatMap(optionalOf(Number.class))
                .map(Number::longValue)
                .orElseThrow(NoResultException::new);
    }

    protected Dialect getDialect() {
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class)
                .getJdbcServices().getDialect();
    }

}
```

I believe your security tool will fail to discover that `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect#getSequenceNextValString` method performs string concatenation, just add sane check of `sequenceName` value, to make sure you are safe.